# Возможно ли сохранить куки для другой страницы?

Tags: javascript

Например, используя

```
SetCookie("asd", "123", dd, "/", "www.google.by", true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы просто делаете куки доступным для www.google.by, но не сохраняете его для www.google.by. То есть этот домен (www.google.by) может получить доступ к этому куки.

Answer (score 0):

Они и так будут сохраняться пока dd>time(). Для сайта google.by, правда.

Comment: Может и будут, но я пытаюсь это сделать с созданного мной веб-приложения. И ничего не выходит. Для моего адреса (127.0.0.1) они сохраняются, для google.com или google.by не хотят!